# Why repmat and reshape so slow for gpuArray in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, gpu

My current task to train multiple networks simultaneously using gpu. I cannot do it right now, so right now I try do some operations with arrays.

```
a = rand(1000, 1000, 'gpuArray');
tic; for i = 1 : 100 a .* a; end; toc;                 % line 1
tic; for i = 1 : 100 repmat(a, 3, 10); end; toc;       % line 2
tic; for i = 1 : 100 reshape(a, 10, 10000); end; toc;  % line 3

b = rand(1000, 1000);
tic; for i = 1 : 100 b .* b; end; toc;                 % line 4
tic; for i = 1 : 100 repmat(b, 3, 10); end; toc;       % line 5
tic; for i = 1 : 100 reshape(b, 10, 10000); end; toc;  % line 6
```

So `line 1` falser than `line 4` but 
`line 2` slower than `line 5` and
`line 3` slower than `line 6`
And for many another arrays with another sizes one can see than CPU faster than GPU for `repmat` and `reshape`.
Can somebody explain what should I do to get expected acceleration?

Comment: Don't modify data on the GPU. Getting data to the GPU (and modifying it) are the two slowest parts of using the GPU.

Comment: So what should I do instead of `reshape` and `repmat`?

Comment: You should create your data locally with `reshape` and `repmat` and *then* cast it as a `gpuArray` after it's a set size

Comment: Ok, I should create corresponding array `a1 = zeros(3 * size(a, 1), 10 * size(a, 2), 'gpuArray')`. And what is the fastest way to copy data? The same question about reshaped array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you saw anything surprising, all you are seeing is asynchronous execution. `a .* a` exits without actually doing anything, it just sets the computation going on the GPU. So all you've timed is how long it took to queue up 100 kernels to execute. You need to either use `gputimeit` or `wait(gpuDevice)` to get proper timings in your code. Maybe by the time `repmat` was executing the queue limit was reached so MATLAB was forced to wait for some of the multiplications to happen, but I can't be sure.

```
a = rand(1000, 1000, 'gpuArray');
b = gather(a);

fprintf('Times for @times: ');
fprintf('GPU: %f secs  ', gputimeit(@()a.*a));
fprintf('CPU: %f secs\n', timeit(@()b.*b));

fprintf('Times for @repmat: ');
fprintf('GPU: %f secs  ', gputimeit(@()repmat(a,3,10)));
fprintf('CPU: %f secs\n', timeit(@()repmat(b,3,10)));

fprintf('Times for @reshape: ');
fprintf('GPU: %f secs  ', gputimeit(@()reshape(a,10,100000)));
fprintf('CPU: %f secs\n', timeit(@()reshape(b,10,100000)));
```

And the output:

```
Times for @times: GPU: 0.000382 secs  CPU: 0.001642 secs
Times for @repmat: GPU: 0.005186 secs  CPU: 0.032809 secs
Times for @reshape: GPU: 0.000053 secs  CPU: 0.000002 secs
```

`reshape` probably really is faster on the CPU (although it's down in the noise) because calling a method on an object takes longer than just inspecting or modifying the properties of an array directly. But really, it's so fast as to be unimportant for any real GPU applications.

If you don't get similar figures on your device then no doubt it's something to do with the quality of your GPU. `repmat` is a high memory bandwidth function - maybe you have a gamer card or laptop chip which has very poor performance for double precision arrays? You could try it in `single`, see if things improve.